# postEvent failed to trigger some times in zk

Tags: java, zk

We do a postEvent call during onClick of a listheader. Most of the times event is triggered and behaved properly. some times it fails. I confirmed it with logger inside second method below not recorded.

```
public void onClick(Event event) {
    if (event.getTarget() != this) {
        return;
    }
    if (editor.isVisible()) {
        return;
    }

    header.setVisible(false);

    add.setVisible(false);

    logger.info("onClick -> before post event");

    if (getLabel() == null || getLabel().trim().length() == 0) {
        **Events.postEvent(new Event(ON_EDIT_NEW_HEADER, this));**
    }

    logger.info("onClick -> after post event");

    // Make the hbox and children visible
    editor.setVisible(true);

    // Set the textbox to have the current value of the listheader
    combobox.setText(getLabel());
    combobox.focus();
    combobox.select();

}



@Listen("onEditNewHeader=dqlistheader")
public void onEditNewDQHeader(Event event) {
    // Create a new empty column the user can use to create another new column if desired.
    logger.info("Inside onEditNewDQHeader --- append header");
    int order = header.getChildren().size();
    ReportColumn column = new ReportColumn(reportType, order);
    header.appendChild(new DQListHeader(column));
    header.invalidate();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your condition

`(getLabel() == null || getLabel().trim().length() == 0)`

is `true`.

Put a log message *in* that `if` block. Your bug is probably that condition.